# Facebook API - Need "User Is Now Logged In" Event?

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the embedded Javascript elements provided by Facebook to make my website support a "Log In with Facebook" feature.  Login works well, and after a user logs in, the "login button" panel auto-fills with profile pics and information from Facebook.  However, I would like to update other elements on my site as well (with the user's "stats" and other personalization information).  I can't seem to find a "hook" to receive notification that the user has logged in successfully.

The login dialog that Facebook opens is in a totally separate browser window, so although I can detect when the user clicks the Login button, I'm not sure how to detect a successful login (ideally I could instruct Facebook to invoke a Javascript function or event handler).  Hopefully I'm just missing something simple!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's the structure of your website or a language you used, but this should be helpful:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        // logged in and connected user, someone you know
    } else {
        // no user session available, someone you dont know
    }
});
```

Read more about it [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/).

Comment: That article link contained the answer I needed.  I was looking for an event to subscribe to, and the article described one.  Thank you for posting the link!